Unable to Generate Docker File in Visual Studio for my .net 8 solution
I am unable to Add a dockerfile support for my .net 8 solution using visual studio, this gives me error saying in order to add docker support the solution file must be located in the same or higher folder
I understand the issue but im confused on how to to handle the structure here.
So basically I have 2 solutions in my Repository, Solution A which is .Net 8 API, Solution B which is .net Framework 4.6.1 API. The structure is as following
MyRepo
|
|____CommonLibraries(common .net standard 2.0 projects)
|
|____CoreAPI
|
|____FrameworkAPI

enter code here

so the issue is both APIS solutions has couple of common c# library projects which are in .net standard 2.0 referenced. when i try to add my dockerfile it gives me error since the referenced common libraries are not in same level or the solution is not in higher level directory.
